# Update an existing attachment's body via REST Api

Tags: visualforce, rest-api, attachment

I'm trying to find a way to update an attachment's body from a custom visual force page I've created. I have the attachment ID but when I try to call a `PATCH` web request on the URL: `http://appid.salesforce.com/services/data/v38.0/sobjects/Attachment/{attachmentId}` I get the following http error:

> BAD REQUEST: Unable to create/update fields: ParentId. Please check
>   the security settings of this field and verify that it is read/write
>   for your profile or permission set.

How can I update an existing attachment's body? I don't want to create a new attachment or anything like that.

The I execute the request is the following:

```
    var objectUrl = http://appid.salesforce.com/services/data/v38.0/sobjects/Attachment/0660L000000WLlH;
    xhr.open("PATCH", objectUrl);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "OAuth " + SFsessionId);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-PrettyPrint", "1");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    xhr.send(attachmentBody);
```

where `attachmentBody` is:

```
var attachment = JSON.stringify({
          name: documentName,
          ContentType: "application/pdf",
          body: pdfAsBase64,
          ParentId: parentid,
          Description: "pdf data"
        });
```

*EDIT:*

The problem is the `ParentId: parentid`. During updating it must not be included. Only once during creation.

Comment: Did you double check FLS and CRUD for your profile to Attachment?

Comment: Shouldn't your URL should be like `https://yourInstance.salesforce.com`. try again while changing `http` -> `https` and instance in the URL apart from what Alexander has mentioned.

Comment: Did you read [this document](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_sobject_insert_update_blob.htm)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you followed [Insert or Update Blob Data](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_sobject_insert_update_blob.htm), odds are, you specified a ParentId. ParentId *must not be set after creation*, as the field can only be set when you create a new Attachment; trying to reparent an attachment is not allowed.

Comment: How can I update an existing attachment's body then?

Comment: @Konstantine Use the patch method described in the document I linked (which I suspect you're already doing), but do not specify a ParentId.

Comment: I don't think that's going to work. Inside the visual force page, I download the attachment's body as a blob and show it in my application. The page itself has no knowledge of the `attachmentId` used so how will it know which attachment to update?

Comment: @Konstantine You need the attachment Id. You're not going to get around that.

Comment: I have the attachment ID but you said I cannot use it. As explained in my question the only thing I'm doing is creating an XHR object with the given url (which contains the attachmentID) and setting the body as the new binary object. I'm not using any apex or salesforce specific stuff, I just want to use the REST Api. What should I do, because just calling that URL with a PATCH method doesn't seem to work...

Comment: @Konstantine you need to create a multipart body, as outlined in the documentation. You can't send a raw body by itself.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60182/discussion-between-konstantine-and-sfdcfox).

Comment: I was stupid and wasn't correctly removing the `parentId` from the body.

Comment: @Konstantine It's okay. Things like that happen all the time. Glad I could help.